# how to swap two structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, swap

I was looking at a code , written in C that swaps places of wto numbers and then two structs. I couldn't understand the second one :

```
#define SWAP(a,b) do {NODE *t = (a) ; (a) = (b) ; (b) = t;}
```

why does it work?? when I declare the t pointer of some struct "Node" so I directly point on a , then all data from b is being transfered to a , and b points to a as well... so I get that they both point on the same object(struct)  .

If I write : `Node t = *a` instead , shouldn't it make it work? or i'm mistaken..

thanks!!

Comment: Can you show the code where this is used?

Comment: this is just example in a slide .. they don't use it .. just explain that it switched pointers or somethig

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you are not transferring any data between the structures. You are just working on pointers which hold the addresses of the structures.

First, you create a pointer `t` which starts to point to whatever `a` was pointing to. Then, you modify pointer `a` so that it points to whatever `b` was pointing to. And finally, you modify `b` to point to whatever `t` is pointing to or IOW to what `a` was pointing before.

So, to sum up: you aren't moving any data between the structures `*a` and `*b` (where `*` means dereferencing the pointer) but just swapping the pointers `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

This code implies that both a and b are pointers of type `NODE *`. Suppose the two structs are the following: realA is a struct of type `NODE` and is pointed to by a; realB is also of type `NODE` and is pointed to by b. Now when you write this:

```
NODE *t = a;
```

here the temporary variable t, being a pointer and assigned to a, points to realA. Now when you see

```
a = b;
```

a no longer points to realA, but gets the address stored in b, so now a points to realB. And finally and similarily,

```
b = t;
```

infers that now b gets the pointer stored in t, which is, in turn, the address of realA.

All in all, only the pointers' contents have been changed; the actual data was untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious guess would be that they are not swapping the stuff that the pointer points to, but just the pointers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This code swaps two pointers and doesn't copy any other data. It seems like a bad macro name;  `SWAP_NODE_PTR` would be better.

Comment: ...or you could call it `SWAP_NODE_PTRS`.  ...or you could ditch the preprocessor hokum, use C++, and get on board with [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/)  :-)

Comment: Do you have C++ with STL for all platforms?